# Create Key Binging in Sublime Text 2 that tags highlighted text with snippet

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings, code-snippets

I have already built a snippet. Which works fine. 
To better help understand the problem, lets say my snippet creates an anchor tag with inline styling:

```
<a style="color:red;font-weight:30px;"></a>
```

My problem is that when I attempt to add a key binding such as:

```
{
"keys": ["ctrl+a"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"name": "Packages/User/red-anchor.sublime-snippet"}
}
```

If I select the highlighted text, then click ctrl+a, it deletes the text and adds the snippet. Rather I would like it to wrap the text inside the snippet. Such as:

```
<a style="color:red;font-weight:30px;">HelloWorld</a>
```

Any ideas? 

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation on snippets](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html), you'll see that there are a number of [variables](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html#environment-variables) that can be accessed, including `$SELECTION`. So, your snippet should be:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<a style="color:red;font-weight:30px;">$SELECTION</a>]]></content>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```